# Why do I have more github clone than visitors?

Tags: github

I made a python library called pycyrpto_tx and I uploaded it on github but I looked at the insight tab and I realized I got more clone than visitors can you please explain what happened?

[image]

As you see I got more than 1,000 clone however I got only 200 visitors from github

[image]

as you see I got more clone than my visitors and there is no reasons that I got this much clones is this error or normal?

Comment: Hypothesis: 1642 clones, but only 19 unique cloners. Somebody has your repo as part of their continuous integration environment.

Comment: @selbie he has 19 unique clones and 12 unique visitors, still looks like wrong statistics.

Comment: @Guy -  visitors are those that physically opened their browsers and navigated to his github project page.  The cloners could come from anywhere. It wouldn't surprise if someone has a build script that does `git clone git://github.com/cheeseCracker/pyCryptoTx` that runs on every check-in.

Comment: @Guy it is real statistic https://github.com/IndentErr/pycrypto_tx this is my repository I cannot even believe this data

Comment: @selbie I am the only one who got right to edit code and I only have one branch

Comment: I have the same issue. In one of my public repositories, into which I'm currently pushing frequently, I have 23 unique cloners and three unique visitors. In another repo, into which I'm currently not actively pushing, I have two unique cloners and three unique visitors. My hypothesis is, that the cloner's statistics are wrong and somehow depend on my own activity.